# What is the difference between "source" and "."?

Tags: bash, scripts

What is the difference between executing a script (e.g. /some/script) with `source /some/script` and `. /some/script` in Bash?

Answer (score 153, accepted):

`source` and `.` are synonymous in **Bash**.

For anyone who might like to verify that the commands are simply synonyms and nothing more, look at the [source code](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git), say for version 4.3, and examine the file [`builtins/source.def`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/builtins/source.def?id=bash-4.3). You will read that both of the built-in commands, [`source`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/builtins/source.def?id=bash-4.3#n23) and [`.`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/builtins/source.def?id=bash-4.3#n38), use the very same function: [`source_builtin`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/builtins/source.def?id=bash-4.3#n113).

Comment: where is this defined? I mean is . an alias for source or is this some thing else?

Comment: exact same thing

Comment: @binW: `.` is the traditional source command, inherited from the ancient bourne shell. `source` is just a bash builtin that does exactly the same as `.`, presumably because it's more readable (a `.` alone may be hard to spot with a small font). You'll see `help source` and `help .` shows the same info.

Comment: @binW: If you look in `man bash` and then search for `source` you'll see that `source filename [arguments]` is a synonym for `. filename [arguments]`.

Answer (score 50):

`.` is synonymous with `source` in bash, but not in POSIX sh, so you should use `.` if your script is run by /bin/sh.  Note that bash claims to run like POSIX sh when called as /bin/sh, but accepts `source` without complaint.

This behaviour has bitten me, scripts tested with bash as /bin/sh fail when run under ash, for example.

Comment: POSIX does not restrict the shell. POSIX just says; the shell shall support at least this and that feature. So a POSIX shell is free to implement additional features as long as the ones described by POSIX are implemented. When the shebang says `#!/bin/sh` you should never assume the shell supports anything but POSIX features though. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18

Comment: You may be affected by the order of looking names up: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/17815/8250

Comment: This answer helped me, since sh is often used in cron.