# Is #!/bin/sh read by the interpreter?

Tags: bash, python, scripts

In `bash` or `sh`, I guess anything which starts with `#` is a **comment**.

But in `bash` scripts we write:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

And in Python scripts, there is:

```
#!/bin/python
```

Does this mean that `#` by itself is a comment whereas `#!` is not?

Comment: And once you start looking at Apparmor profiles, you'll see `#include`. There too, the `#` isn't meant as a comment.

Comment: @vasa1 But the key point that's often not appreciated about hashbang lines at the beginning of shell scripts is that [they *are* comments](http://askubuntu.com/a/238020/22949).

Answer (score 110, accepted):

#### The `#!` line is used *before* the script is run, then ignored *when* the script runs.

You're asking what the difference is between a [shebang line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) and an ordinary comment.

A line starting with `#!` is just as much a comment as any other line that starts with `#`. This is true if the `#!` is the first line of the file, or anywhere else. `#!/bin/sh` *has an effect*, but **it is not read by the interpreter itself**.

`#` is not a comment in all programming languages but, as you know, it's a comment in Bourne-style shells including `sh` and `bash` (as well as most non-Bourne-style shells, like `csh`). It's [also a comment in Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#comments). And it is a comment in a variety of configuration files that are not really scripts at all (like `/etc/fstab`).

Suppose a shell script begins with `#!/bin/sh`. That is a comment, and the interpreter (the shell) ignores everything on the line after the `#` character.

The purpose of a `#!` line is not to give information to the interpreter. The purpose of the `#!` line is to tell the operating system (or whatever process launches the interpreter) *what to use as the interpreter*.

- If you invoke the script as an executable file, for example, by running `./script.sh`, the system consults the first line to see if begins with `#!`, followed by zero or more spaces, followed by a command. If it does, it runs that command with the name of the script as its argument. In this example, it runs `/bin/sh script.sh` (or, technically, `/bin/sh ./script.sh`).
- If you invoke the script by explicitly calling the interpreter, the `#!` line is never consulted. So, if you run `sh script.sh`, the first line has no effect. If `script2.sh`'s first line is `#!/usr/games/nibbles`, running `sh script2.sh` will not try to open the script in `nibbles` (but `./script2.sh` will).

You'll notice that in neither case does the script's extension (`.sh`), if it has one, impact how it is run. In a Unix-like system, this doesn't ordinarily affect how the script is run. On some other systems, like Windows, the `#!` shebang line might be ignored entirely by the system, and the extension might determine what runs the scripts. (This doesn't mean you need to give your scripts extensions, but it is one of the reasons why if you do, they should be correct.)

`#!` was chosen to serve this purpose precisely *because* `#` begins a comment. The `#!` line is for the system, not the interpreter, and it should be ignored by the interpreter.

#### Shebang Line for Bash Scripts

You (originally) said you use `#!/bin/sh` for `bash` scripts. You should only do that if the script doesn't require any of `bash`'s extensions--`sh` needs to be able to run the script. `sh` is not always a symlink to `bash`. Often, including on [all remotely recent Debian and Ubuntu systems](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh), `sh` is a symlink to `dash`.

#### Shebang Line for Python Scripts

You also said (in the first version of your question, before editing) that you start your Python scripts with `#!/bin/sh read by the interpretor`. If you mean that literally, then you should definitely stop doing that. If `hello.py` begins with that line, running `./hello.py` executes:

```
/bin/sh read by the interpretor hello.py
```

`/bin/sh` will try to execute a script called `read` (with `by the interpretor hello.py` as its arguments), `read` will (hopefully) not be found, and your Python script will never be seen by a Python interpreter.

If you're making this mistake but not having the problem I'm describing, you're probably invoking your Python scrips by explicitly specifying the interpreter (e.g., `python hello.py`), causing the first line to be ignored. When you distribute your scripts to others, or use them a long while later, it may not be clear that this is necessary for them to work. It's best to fix them now. Or at least remove the first line entirely, so that when they fail to run with `./` the error message will make sense.

For Python scripts, if you know where the Python interpreter is (or is going to be), you can write the `#!` line the same way:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

Or, if it's a Python 3 script, you should specify `python3`, since [`python` is almost always Python 2](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/):

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

However, the problem is that while `/bin/sh` is supposed to always exist, and `/bin/bash` almost always exists on systems where `bash` comes with the OS, Python may exist in a variety of places.

Therefore, many Python programmers use this instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

(Or `#!/usr/bin/env python3` for Python 3.)

This makes the script rely on `env` being in the "right place" instead of relying on `python` being in the right place. That's a good thing, because:

- `env` is almost always located in `/usr/bin`.
- On most systems, whichever `python` *should* run your script is the one that appears first in the `PATH`. Starting `hello.py` with `#!/usr/bin/env python` make `./hello.py` run `/usr/bin/env python hello.py`, which is (virtually) equivalent to running `python hello.py`.

The reason you cannot use `#!python` is that:

- You want the interpreter specified to be given by an absolute path (i.e., starting with `/`).
- The calling process would execute `python` [in the current directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/77584/11938). Searching the path when the command doesn't contain a slash is specific shell behavior.

Occasionally a Python or other script that isn't a shell script will have a shebang line starting with `#!/bin/sh ...` where `...` is some other code. This is sometimes correct, because there are some ways to invoke the Bourne-compatible shell (`sh`) with arguments to make it invoke a Python interpreter. (One of the arguments will probably contain `python`.) However, for most purposes, `#!/usr/bin/env python` is simpler, more elegant,  and more likely to work the way you want.

#### Shebang Lines in Other Languages

Many programming and scripting languages, and some other file formats, use `#` as a comment. For any of them, a file in the language can be run by a program that takes it as an argument by specifying the program on the first line after `#!`.

In some programming languages, `#` is not normally a comment, but as a special case the first line is ignored if it starts with `#!`. This facilitates the use of `#!` syntax even though `#` doesn't otherwise make a line a comment.

#### Shebang Lines for Files That Don't Run As Scripts

While it's less intuitive, any file whose file format can accommodate a first line starting with `#!` followed by the full path of an executable can have a shebang line. If you do this, and the file is marked executable, then you can run it like a program...causing it to be opened like a document.

Some applications use this behavior intentionally. For example, in VMware, `.vmx` files define virtual machines. You can "run" a virtual machine as though it were a script because these files are marked executable and have a shebang line causing them to be opened in a VMware utility.

#### Shebang Lines for Files That Don't Run as Scrips but Act Like Scripts Anyway

`rm` removes files. It is not a scripting language. However, a file that starts `#!/bin/rm` and is marked executable can be run, and when you run it, `rm` is invoked on it, deleting it.

This is often conceptualized as "the file deletes itself." But the file is not really running at all. This is more like the situation described above for `.vmx` files.

Still, because the `#!` line facilitates the running of a simple command (including command-line arguments), you can perform some scripting this way. As a simple example of a "script" more sophisticated than `#!/bin/rm`, consider:

```
#!/usr/bin/env tee -a
```

This takes user input interactively, echoes it back to the user line-by-line, and appends it to the end of the "script" file.

Useful? Not very. Conceptually interesting? Totally! Yes. (Somewhat.)

#### Conceptually Similar Programming/Scripting Concepts (just for fun)

- Scripts/programs that are [multiple languages at once](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyglot_(computing)), for example, [to simulate hashbang functionality in OSes that didn't have it](https://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.qpsmtpd/2007/01/msg6112.html).

  <sup>(These programs are called *polyglots*, but this is not to be confused with [the other sense of *polyglot* in software development](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd483224.aspx), a program/project where different parts are written in different languages.)</sup>
- [Metacommands](http://qb64.net/wiki/index.php?title=Metacommand) in QBasic/QuickBASIC, which signaled to the compiler (for compiled code) options for code generation, but were part of comments and thus ignored during actual compilation/interpretation.

Comment: @Rinzwind Thx! (Btw this answer doesn't originate elsewhere, if that's what you're wondering.)

Comment: @Rinzwind Don't worry, with 8 upvotes after 1 hour it is likely to raise much further :-)

Comment: If it's always ignored, then what does Pythons `-x` flag do?

Comment: @gerrit Good question. In any language where the intepreter/compiler reports messages with line numbers, comments' *contents* are ignored, but comment-lines are still *counted*. Adding a comment or blank line before a line of code still results in that line of code having its line number incremented. `-x` "skip[s] the first line..." the 2nd line gets numbered `1` instead of `2`, the 3rd line `2` instead of `3`, etc. This is why you shouldn't use that flag. ;) `-x` is for scripting on non-Unix-like OSes that have shebang-like syntax not starting with `#` (thus not a Python comment).

Comment: In Perl, if the interpreter is started directly (`perl script.pl` vs. `./script.pl`) then the interpreter *will* read the shebang line to parse flags such as `-w`. It's not recommended to rely on this feature though.

Comment: an example of a program that needs at leat an argument on the shebang line to make the shebang work: awk: usually the first line is `#!/path/to/awk -f` and the rest of the file contains the awk commands (without the -f, awk will usually have trouble interpreting the rest)

Comment: @OlivierDulac Yes--`awk` requires `-f` to read its "program" from a file. *In a sense*, the interpreter is `awk -f`. Manually invoking `awk` to run an `awk` script uses `-f` too: `awk -f script`. This doesn't make `awk` particularly special. For example, a Python script intended to be run with unbuffered I/O could start `#!/usr/bin/env python -u` and be run `./program` (just `program` if it's in the PATH of course) or `python -u program`. In contrast, when `perl` behaves as OrangeDog described that's quite different--the interpreter takes flags from the `#!` line even if invoked without them.

Answer (score 7):

A shebang is the character sequence consisting of the characters number sign and exclamation mark (e.g. "#!") when it occurs as the initial two characters on the initial line of a script.

Under *nix operating systems, when a script starting with a shebang is run, the program loader parses the rest of the script's initial line as an interpreter directive; the specified interpreter program is run instead, passing to it as an argument the path that was initially used when attempting to run the script. For example, if a script is named with the path "path/to/your-script", and it starts with the following line:

```
#!/bin/sh
```

then the program loader is instructed to run the program "/bin/sh" instead e.g. the Bourne shell or a compatible shell, passing "path/to/your-script" as the first argument.

Accordingly, it a script is named with the path "path/to/python-script" and it starts with the following line:

```
#!/bin/python
```

then the program loaded is instructed to run the program "/bin/python" instead e.g. Python interpreter, passing "path/to/python-script" as the first argument.

In short "#" will comment out a line while the character sequence "#!" occurring as the first two characters on the initial line of a script has meaning outlined as above.

For details see [Why do some scripts start with #! ... ?](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/faq/part3/section-16.html)

<sup>**Source:** Some sections of this answer are derived (with slight modification) from [Shebang (Unix)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) on [English Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page) (by *Wikipedia contributors*). This article is [licensed under CC-BY-SA 3.0](http://wikimediafoundation.org/wiki/Terms_of_Use), same as user content here on AU, so this derivation is permitted with attribution.</sup>

Answer (score 5):

`#!` is called the `shebang` when it occurs as the initial two characters on the initial line of a script. It is used in scripts to indicate an interpreter for execution. The `shebang` is for the operating system(kernel), not for the shell; so it won't be interpreted as a comment.

**Courtesy:** http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29

> In general, if a file is executable, but actually not an executable
>   (binary) program, and such a line is present, the program specified
>   after #! is started with the scriptname and all its arguments. These
>   two characters # and ! have to be the first two bytes in the file!

**Detailed Info:** http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/basics#the_shebang

Answer (score 0):

**No, it is only used by the `exec` system call of the Linux kernel, and treated as a comment by the interpreter**

When you do on bash:

```
./something
```

on Linux, this calls the `exec` system call with the path `./something`.

This line of the kernel gets called on the file passed to `exec`: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.8/fs/binfmt_script.c#L25

```
if ((bprm->buf[0] != '#') || (bprm->buf[1] != '!'))
```

It reads the very first bytes of the file, and compares them to `#!`.

If the comparison is true, then the rest of the line is parsed by the Linux kernel, which makes another `exec` call with path `/usr/bin/env python` and current file as the first argument:

```
/usr/bin/env python /path/to/script.py
```

and this works for any scripting language that uses `#` as a comment character.

And yes, you can make an infinite loop with:

```
printf '#!/a\n' | sudo tee /a
sudo chmod +x /a
/a
```

Bash recognizes the error:

```
-bash: /a: /a: bad interpreter: Too many levels of symbolic links
```

`#!` just happens to be human readable, but that is not required.

If the file started with different bytes, then the `exec` system call would use a different handler. The other most important built-in handler is for ELF executable files: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.8/fs/binfmt_elf.c#L1305 which checks for bytes `7f 45 4c 46` (which also happens to be human readable for `.ELF`). Let's confirm that by reading the 4 first bytes of `/bin/ls`, which is an ELF executable:

```
head -c 4 "$(which ls)" | hd
```

output:

```
00000000  7f 45 4c 46                                       |.ELF|
00000004
```

So when the kernel sees those bytes, it takes the ELF file, puts it into memory correctly, and starts a new process with it. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8352535/how-does-kernel-get-an-executable-binary-file-running-under-linux/31394861#31394861

Finally, you can add your own shebang handlers with the `binfmt_misc` mechanism. For example, you can add a [custom handler for `.jar` files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667830/running-a-jar-file-without-directly-calling-java). This mechanism even supports handlers by file extension. Another application is to [transparently run executables of a different architecture with QEMU](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41889/how-can-i-chroot-into-a-filesystem-with-a-different-architechture).

I don't think POSIX specifies shebangs however: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/346214/32558 , although it does mention in on rationale sections, and in the form "if executable scripts are supported by the system something may happen".