# Why doesn't rc.local run all my commands, and what can I do about it?

Tags: startup, execute-command, scripts

I have the following `rc.local` script:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

sh /home/incero/startup_script.sh
/bin/chmod +x /script.sh
sh /script.sh

exit 0
```

The first line, `startup_script.sh` actually downloads the `script.sh` file to `/script.sh` referred to in the third line.

Unfortunately, it appears that it is not making the script executeable or running the script. Running the `rc.local` file manually after having started works perfectly. Can chmod not be run at startup or something?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

*You can skip all the way down to **A Quick Fix** but that's not necessarily the best option. So I recommend reading all this first.*

#### `rc.local` doesn't tolerate errors.

`rc.local` doesn't provide a way to intelligently recover from errors. If any command fails, it stops running. The first line, `#!/bin/sh -e`, causes it to be executed in a shell invoked with the `-e` flag. The `-e` flag is what makes a script (in this case, `rc.local`) stop running the first time a command fails within it.

*You want `rc.local` to behave like this. If a command fails, you do **not** want it to continue on with whatever other startup commands might be relying on it having succeeded.*

So if any command fails, the subsequent commands will not run. The problem here is that `/script.sh` did not run (not that it failed, see below), so most likely some command before it failed. But which one?

#### Was it `/bin/chmod +x /script.sh`?

No.

`chmod` runs fine at any time. Provided the filesystem that contains `/bin` was mounted, you can run `/bin/chmod`. And `/bin` is mounted before `rc.local` runs.

When run as root, `/bin/chmod` rarely fails. It will fail if the file it operates on is read-only, and *might* fail if the filesystem it's on doesn't supported permissions. Neither is likely here.

By the way, `sh -e` is the *only* reason it would actually be a problem if `chmod` failed. When you run a script file by explicitly invoking its interpreter, it doesn't matter if the file is marked executable. Only if it said `/script.sh` would the file's executable bit matter. Since it says `sh /script.sh`, it doesn't (unless of course `/script.sh` *calls itself* while it runs, which could fail from it not being executable, but it's unlikely it calls itself).

#### So what failed?

`sh /home/incero/startup_script.sh` failed. Almost certainly.

We know it ran, because it downloaded `/script.sh`.

<sup>(Otherwise, it would be important to make sure it did run, in case somehow `/bin` was not in [PATH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29)--`rc.local` doesn't necessarily have the same `PATH` as you have when you're logged in. If `/bin` weren't in `rc.local`'s path, this would require `sh` to be run as `/bin/sh`. Since it did run, `/bin` is in `PATH`, which means you can run other commands that are located in `/bin`, without fully qualifying their names. For example, you can run just `chmod` rather than `/bin/chmod`. However, in keeping with your style in `rc.local`, I've used fully qualified names for all commands except `sh`, whenever I am suggesting you run them.)</sup>

We can be pretty sure `/bin/chmod +x /script.sh` never ran (or you would see that `/script.sh` was executed). And we know `sh /script.sh` wasn't run either.

But it downloaded `/script.sh`. It succeeded! How could it fail?

#### Two Meanings of Success

There are two different things a person might mean when s/he says a command succeeded:

1. It did what you wanted it to do.
2. It reported that it succeeded.

And so it is for failure. When a person says a command failed, it could mean:

1. It did not do what you wanted it to do.
2. It reported that it failed.

A script run with `sh -e`, like `rc.local`, will stop running the first time a command *reports that it failed*. It doesn't make a difference what the command actually did.

Unless you intend for `startup_script.sh` to report failure when it does what you want, this is a bug in `startup_script.sh`.

- Some bugs prevent a script from doing what you want it to do. They affect what programmers call its [side effects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_%28computer_science%29).
- And some bugs prevent a script from reporting correctly whether or not it succeeded. They affect what programmers call its [return value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value) (which in this case is an [exit status](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status)).

It's most likely that `startup_script.sh` did everything it should, *except* reported that it failed.

#### How Success Or Failure Is Reported

A script is a list of zero or more commands. Each command has an exit status. Assuming there are no failures in actually running the script (for example, if the interpreter couldn't read the next line of the script while running it), the exit status of a script is:

- `0` (success) if the script was blank (i.e., had no commands).
- **`N`**, if the script ended as a result of the command `exit N`, where **`N`** is some exit code.
- The exit code of the last command that ran in the script, otherwise.

When an executable runs, it reports its own exit code--they're not just for scripts. (And technically, exit codes from scripts are the exit codes returned by the shells that run them.)

For example, if a C program ends with `exit(0);`, or `return 0;` in its `main()` function, the code `0` is given to the operating system, which provides it to calling process (which may, for example, be the shell from which the program was run).

`0` means the program succeeded. Every other number means it failed. (This way, different numbers can sometimes refer to different reasons the program failed.)

#### Commands Meant to Fail

Sometimes, you run a program with the intention that it will fail. In these situations, you might think of its failure as success, even though it is not a bug that the program reports failure. For example, you might use `rm` on a file you suspect already does not exist, just to make sure it's deleted.

Something like this is probably happening in `startup_script.sh`, just before it stops running. The *last command to run* in the script is probably reporting failure (even though its "failure" might be totally fine or even necessary), which makes the script report failure.

#### Tests Meant to Fail

One special kind of command is *a test*, by which I mean a command run for its return value rather than its side effects. That is, a test is a command that is run so that its exit status can be examined (and acted upon).

For example, suppose I forget if 4 is equal to 5. Fortunately, I know shell scripting:

```
if [ 4 -eq 5 ]; then
    echo "Yeah, they're totally the same."
fi
```

Here, the test `[ -eq 5 ]` fails because it turns out 4 ≠ 5 after all. That doesn't mean the test didn't perform correctly; it did. It's job was to check if 4 = 5, then report success if so, and failure if not.

You see, in shell scripting, success can also mean *true*, and failure can also mean *false*.

Even though the `echo` statement never runs, the `if` block as a whole does return success.

However, supposed I'd written it shorter:

```
[ 4 -eq 5 ] && echo "Yeah, they're totally the same."
```

This is common shorthand. `&&` is a [boolean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra) *and* operator. A `&&` expression, which consists of `&&` with statements on either side, returns false (failure) unless both sides return true (success). Just like a normal *and*.

If someone asks you, "did Derek go to the mall and think about a butterfly?" and you know Derek didn't go to the mall, you don't have to bother figuring out if he thought of a butterfly.

Similarly, if the command to the left of `&&` fails (false), the whole `&&` expression immediately fails (false). The statement on the right side of `&&` is never run.

Here, `[ 4 -eq 5 ]` runs. It "fails" (returning false). So the whole `&&` expression fails. `echo "Yeah, they're totally the same."` never runs. Everything behaved as it should be, but this command reports *failure* (even though the otherwise equivalent `if` conditional above reports success).

If that were the last statement in a script (and the script got to it, rather than terminating at some point before it), the whole script would report *failure*.

*There's lots of tests besides this. For example, there are tests with `||` ("or"). However, the above example should be sufficient to explain what tests are, and make it possible for you to effectively use documentation to determine if a particular statement/command is a test.*

#### `sh` vs. `sh -e`, Revisited

Since [the `#!` line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashbang) (see also [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/238002/is-bin-sh-read-by-the-interpreter)) at the top of `/etc/rc.local` has `sh -e`, the operating system runs the script as though it were invoked with the command:

```
sh -e /etc/rc.local
```

In contrast, your other scripts, such as `startup_script.sh`, run *without* the `-e` flag:

```
sh /home/incero/startup_script.sh
```

Consequently they keep running even when a command in them reports failure.

This is normal and good. `rc.local` should be invoked with `sh -e` and most other scripts--including most scripts run by `rc.local`--should not.

Just make sure to remember the difference:

- Scripts run with `sh -e` exit reporting failure the first time a command they contain exits reporting failure.

  It's as though the script were a single long command consisting of all the commands in the script joined with `&&` operators.
- Scripts run with `sh` (without `-e`) continue running until they get to a command that terminates (exits out of) them, or to the very end of the script. The success or failure of every command is essentially irrelevant (unless the next command checks it). The script exits with the exit status of the last command run.

#### Helping Your Script Understand It's Not Such a Failure After All

How can you keep your script from thinking it failed when it didn't?

You look at what happens just before it's done running.

1. If a command failed when it ought to have succeeded, figure out why, and fix the problem.
2. If a command failed, and that was the right thing to happen, then prevent that failure status from propagating.

   - One way to keep a failure status from propagating is to run another command that succeeds. `/bin/true` has no side effects and reports success (just as `/bin/false` does nothing and also fails).
   - Another is to make sure the script is terminated by `exit 0`.

     That's not necessarily the same thing as `exit 0` being at the end of the script. For example, there might be an `if`-block where the script exits inside.

It's best to know what causes your script to report failure, before making it report success. If it really is failing in some way (in the sense of not doing what you want it to do), you don't really want it to report success.

#### A Quick Fix

If you can't make `startup_script.sh` exit reporting success, you can change the command in `rc.local` that runs it, so that command reports success even though `startup_script.sh` did not.

Currently you have:

```
sh /home/incero/startup_script.sh
```

This command has the same side effects (i.e., the side effect of running `startup_script.sh`), but always reports success:

```
sh /home/incero/startup_script.sh || /bin/true
```

Remember, it's better to know why `startup_script.sh` reports failure, and fix it.

#### How the Quick Fix Works

This is actually an example of a `||` test, an *or* test.

Suppose you ask if I took out the trash or brushed the owl. If I took out the trash, I can truthfully say "yes," even if I don't remember whether or not I brushed the owl.

The command to the left of `||` runs. If it succeeds (true), then the right-hand side doesn't have to run. So if `startup_script.sh` reports success, the `true` command never runs.

However, if `startup_script.sh` reports failure *[I didn't take out the trash]*, then the result of `/bin/true` *[if I brushed the owl]* matters.

`/bin/true` always returns success (or *true*, as we sometimes call it). Consequently, the whole command succeeds, and the next command in `rc.local` can run.

#### An additional note on success/failure, true/false, zero/nonzero.

*Feel free to ignore this. You might want to read this if you program in more than one language, though (i.e., not just shell scripting).*

It is a point of great confusion for shell scripters taking up programming languages like C, and for C programmers taking up shell scripting, to discover:

- In shell scripting:

  1. A return value of `0` means *success* and/or *true*.
  2. A return value of something other than `0` means *failure* and/or *false*.
- In C programming:

  1. A return value of `0` means *false*..
  2. A return value of something other than `0` means *true*.
  3. There is no simple rule for what means success and what means failure. Sometimes `0` means success, other times it means failure, other times it means that the sum of the two numbers you just added is zero. Return values in general programming are used to signal a wide variety of different sorts of information.
  4. A program's numeric exit status should indicate success or failure in accordance with the rules for shell scripting. That is, even though `0` means false in your C program, you still make your program return `0` as its exit code if you want it to report it succeeded (which the shell then interprets as *true*).

Comment: wow great answer! Theres a lot of info in there that I didn't know. Returning 0 at the end of the first script causes the rest of the script to execute (well I can tell that the chmod +x ran). Unfortunately it looks like the /usr/bin/wget in my script is failing to retrieve a webpage to put in script.sh. I am guessing that the network isn't ready by the time this rc.local script executes. Where can I put this command so that it will run when the network has started, and automatically on startup?

Comment: I have 'hacked' it for now by running sudo visudo, adding the following line: username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
running 'startup applications' program (what is the CLI command for this?), and adding startup_script to this, whilst startupscript now runs script.sh with the sudo command beforehand to run as root (no longer needs password). No doubt this is super insecure and terrible, but this is just for a custom pxe-boot live distro disc.

Comment: @Stu2000 Assuming `incero` (I assume that's the username) *is an administrator anyway*, and thus is allowed to run any command as `root` (by entering their own user password), that isn't *super insecure and terrible*. If you want other solutions, **I recommend posting a new question about this**. One problem was why the commands in `rc.local` didn't run (and you also checked to see what would happen if you made them continue to run). Now you have a different problem: you want to get the machine network-connected before `rc.local` runs, or schedule the running of `startup_script.sh` later.

Comment: @Stu2000 This seems to have its own complexities, with more info needed (another reason for a new question). Why can't `/script.sh` be in the image containing the system? This is a PXE image; presumably a machine booting it is network-connected very early on. So it's important to know/find why it's not. Is the LAN with the tftp server not the same LAN as the network that contains (or provides a gateway to) `script.sh`? If so, does it have to be? Are you *testing* by PXE booting it? (Plus there are likely people who can answer who are more knowledgeable than me about these particular issues.)

Comment: Thanks Eliah. Your right; there are two questions here. I have a reasonable solution for now. Thank you for your quite considerable help/info.

Comment: I have since come back to this issue, edited the rc.local and found wget didn't 'work'. Adding `/usr/bin/sudo service networking restart` to the startup script before the wget command resulted in wget then working.

Comment: @EliahKagan wonderful exhaustive answer. I hardly came across a better documentation on `rc.local`

Comment: Even though the long explanation is plausible, the use -e breaks all unix convention for handling for rc.local.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can (in Unix variants I use) override the default behavior by changing:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
```

To:

```
#!/bin/sh
```

At the start of the script.  The "-e" flag instructs sh to exit on the first error.  The long name of that flag is "errexit", so the original line is equivalent to:

```
#!/bin/sh --errexit
```

Comment: yes, removing `-e` works on raspbian jessie.

Comment: The `-e` is there for a reason. I wouldn't do that if I were you. But I'm not your parents.

Answer (score 2):

@Bryce 's [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/706040/253096) is perfectly fine in certain situations--depending on what you are using `rc.local` for.  If it's absolutely critical that nothing happen after the first error, of course `-e` is exactly what you want.  But `rc.local` can be used for many purposes, and you could have things in there that are not dependent on other things in there having succeeded.

Most of my reason for answering, though, is to explain what you can do to figure out where your rc.local went wrong.  I highly recommend having something like this right at the beginning of your rc.local script:

```
exec 2> /tmp/rc.local.log      # send stderr from rc.local to a log file
exec 1>&2                      # send stdout to the same log file
set -x                         # tell sh to display commands before execution

date                           # good practice to record when stuff happened
```

Comment: Thanks @JasonHarrison!  fixing now.

Answer (score -4):

change first line from:
`#!/bin/sh -e`
to
`!/bin/sh -e`

Comment: The syntax with `#!` is the correct one. (At least, the `#!` part is correct. And the rest usually works well to, for `rc.local`.) See [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) and [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/238002/is-bin-sh-read-by-the-interpreter). _Anyways, welcome to Ask Ubuntu!_