# Why is the command in /etc/rc.local not executed during startup?

Tags: boot, server, scripts, startup, tt-rss

I have a single command in my `/etc/rc.local` script that is supposed to start the update daemon for [Tiny Tiny RSS](http://tt-rss.org/redmine/projects/tt-rss/wiki) during startup, but the script is not executed during startup. Why?

The entire /etc/rc.local file:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

/sbin/start-stop-daemon -b -c www-data:www-data -S -x /usr/bin/php /var/www/ttrss/update_daemon2.php -- -quiet

exit 0
```

`/etc/rc.local` is executable:

```
# ls -l /etc/rc.local
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 342 May 25 16:14 /etc/rc.local
```

`/etc/init.d/rc.local` exists and is executable:

```
# ls -l /etc/init.d/rc.local
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 801 Jul 27  2012 /etc/init.d/rc.local
```

`/etc/init.d/rc.local` is supposed to be executed at startup for this runlevel:

```
# runlevel 
N 2
# ls -l /etc/rc2.d/S99rc.local 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 Sep 22  2012 /etc/rc2.d/S99rc.local -> ../init.d/rc.local
```

If I manually call /etc/rc.local from the command line the update_daemon loads...

```
# /etc/rc.local
# ps ax | grep update_daemon2.php
2233 ?        S      0:00 /usr/bin/php /media/sda5/www/news/update_daemon2.php -quiet
2234 ?        S      0:00 /usr/bin/php /media/sda5/www/news/update_daemon2.php -quiet
```

... which I have to remember to do every time my server restarts until this problem is fixed.

[Similar](https://askubuntu.com/q/287590) [questions](https://askubuntu.com/q/9853) [already](https://askubuntu.com/q/239600/161623) exist, but so far I've been unable to apply the information within to my specific problem.

**Why is the command in rc.local not executed during startup?**

Comment: May be due to the `requiretty` setting. When you are logged-in, you are executing the script in TTY but during the system boot, it is not in TTY. This link may assist you https://www.shell-tips.com/2014/09/08/sudo-sorry-you-must-have-a-tty-to-run-sudo/ Thanks.

Answer (score 26):

`rc.local` script exits if any error occurs while executing any of its commands (mention the `-e` flag in `#!/bin/sh -e`).

It is possible that some prerequisites are not met when you try to run your commands when `rc.local` execution takes place, so your command execution fails.

I encountered the same thing while manually setting cpu governor and failing to do so in `rc.local`. Here's my custom workaround, which uses `update-rc.d` to make your commands run on startup:

1. Create a file `myscript.sh` in directory `/etc/init.d` with a heading: `#!/bin/sh`
2. Put your custom commands as the content
3. Make it executable: `sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/myscript.sh`
4. Create symlinks for your script for various runlevels: `sudo update-rc.d myscript.sh defaults`

Also, you could check `/etc/network/if-up.d` scripts and see if you could trigger your commands when networking starts.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. My setup has changed since I posted the question, so I am unable to test if your answer would have solved the problem.

Comment: Please tell me what does the step-4 does? I'm new to `update-rc.d`

Answer (score 19):

Make sure the rc.local script is executable:

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/rc.local
```

Then, enable it:

```
sudo systemctl enable rc-local.service
```

Reboot the system or start the script manually by running:

```
sudo systemctl start  rc-local.service
```

The service status can be displayed by running:

```
$ sudo systemctl status rc-local.service
● rc-local.service - /etc/rc.local Compatibility
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/rc-local.service; static; vendor preset: enabled) 
Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/rc-local.service.d
           └─debian.conf
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2018-04-02 10:39:44 -03; 1s ago
  Process: 2044 ExecStart=/etc/rc.local start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 2049 (svscanboot)
Tasks: 3
 Memory: 556.0K
CPU: 10ms
CGroup: /system.slice/rc-local.service
```

Comment: You don't need to manually enable the service. If the file exists and is executable, systemd will automatically enable the `rc-local` service.

Comment: Do sudo /etc/rc.local and make sure it works.

Answer (score 8):

i had some similar problem in rc.local not executing at startup

sshades provided me with the following answer :

> Ubuntu is now using systemd, and rc.local is now considered a service which is turned "off" by default. You can turn rc.local "on" by entering the following command and rebooting:

```
sudo systemctl enable rc-local.service
```

> https://askubuntu.com/a/770033/395498

although i haven't tested his solution i think it sounds logical and will work. However :

I also found a solution that adding a script to ./.config/autostart-scripts/ will do the trick

Comment: Getting this error . The unit files have no installation config (WantedBy, RequiredBy, Also, Alias
settings in the [Install] section, and DefaultInstance for template units).
This means they are not meant to be enabled using systemctl.
Possible reasons for having this kind of units are:
1) A unit may be statically enabled by being symlinked from another unit's
   .wants/ or .requires/ directory.
2) A unit's purpose may be to act as a helper for some other unit which has
   a requirement dependency on it.

Comment: I am also getting this error. If `rc.local` is turned off, what is the alternative?

Answer (score 7):

We had this problem on some hosted servers loading FW rules.

On these boxes they reboot VERY quickly and we found just putting a "sleep 1" in rc.local before the load statements seems to fix the issue. I guess it gave a little time for the interfaces to settle before loading the FW rules.

Comment: Thank you. `sleep 1` solved my problem. Interesting I have a lot of servers but only one has this problem.

Answer (score 5):

try `sudo sysv-rc-conf` and check out if `rc.local` is enabled

```
rc.local         [ ]   [x]   [x]   [x]   [x]   [ ]   [ ]   [ ]
```

Comment: Yes, it is enabled.

Comment: does this command need to be installed?

Comment: @jcollum yes, it is a program from a package named the same. To install, type `sudo apt install sysv-rc-conf`

Comment: `rc.local` is not even in my list of services!

Answer (score 2):

I once edited `rc.local` with Notepad in Windows and it began to have this problem.

In this case, using a text editor supports EOL Conversion, such as Notepad++, to convert the EOL style to 'Unix', may solve it.

You can also do it by `:set ff=unix` in Vim.

Answer (score 1):

I found in Ubuntu lxc containers that if rc.local has a perfectly correct shebang
e.g.

```
#!/bin/sh
```

it fails, but if you remove the shebang it works.

Not got to the bottom of why or what shell it uses I think it bombs on first non-zero too. (In other Ubuntu installs proper shebang is not an issue)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make sure that `/etc/rc.local` is executed during the server startup with the command:

`sudo systemctl enable rc-local.service`