# How to make some commands executable?

Tags: command-line, xubuntu, startup, python3, execute-command

I have some python commands that I want to run at startup, what I need to do everytime I boot my machine is manually start them by changing directories and executing them.
Is it possible to make an exectable file which will execute a list of commands in the terminal?
Or is it possible to let those command run at the startup ?
It will be very handy to make those run by a simple double click instead of manually doing that.

Comment: in your system settings, there should be a setting for declaring programs to run at start

Comment: Please clarify what commands you need to run, to do what. Furthermore, do they need to run from their directory? Do you need them to run in terminal? Also, It seems you need to run them on *log in* rather than startup, right?

Comment: @JacobVlijm the commands I use to run are pythonfiles, which help me run a bot, 
python3 botname.py
What I need to do is, make them run as soon as I'm logged in or as soon as the System boots, maybe I got confused between the two, using the solution ravexina provided, I'm able to add those on startup, but the bot doesn't run the way it should as the wifi isn't turned on, I'm not sure what to do to make it run the way I want.

Comment: Ah, censorship now too. Excellent.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make the file executable using cmd `chmod +x filename.py` as your say it is a python file.

After press start button or open Ubuntu dash and search `StartUp`

[image: Startup Luncher]

Click on `Add`

[image: Menu list in Startup]

You will able to see as above now enter name of command and provide path of file, if you want can add some comment.
now click on add, your program will run on startup

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `rc.local` to run your commands at the startup (boot time).

1. First `cd` into the commands directory:

   ```
   cd /path/to/commands
   ```
2. Then make them executable (`*.py` means all files with the `py` extension):

   ```
   chmod +x *.py
   ```

   - You can run the command one by one on all files too:

     ```
     chmod +x command1 command2 cmd3
     ```
3. Open `/etc/rc.local` file using an editor you like:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/rc.local
   ```
4. Addd the commands like:

   ```
    ./path/to/commands/command1
    ./path/to/commands/command2
    ...
   ```
5. Save the file and make sure `rc.local` itself is executable:

   ```
    test -x /etc/rc.local || sudo chmod +x /etc/rc.local
   ```

You are done, in each boot your commands get executed.

Comment: It is hihgly unlikely that OP actually means *Startup*. Most likely the commands should run on log in.

Comment: Also see [After upgrade to 16.04 LTS rc.local is not executing a command](https://askubuntu.com/a/770033/178692)

Comment: @steeldriver I really can't remember that the service was enabled or not on my 16.04 :D thanks for pointing it out...

Comment: @JacobVlijm I just leave it here as an alternative ;)

Comment: This doesn't work :( yes my files are executable.

Comment: @SchezanMansuri check the link that  steeldriver provided ...

Comment: Let me get back, I'm checking this out. thank you @ravexina

Comment: I'm able to add those in startup now, but the problem is that the wifi isn't turned on before the command runs, I need my system connected to the internet before executing it. I'm trying to search for a workaround.