# I need help adding a script to /etc/rc.local

Tags: scripts, startup

This seems simple but I can't seem to figure it out. I am trying to write a script to mount a drive on startup.
the command I want to run is:

`google-drive-ocamlfuse ~/gdrive`

But i want it to run each time i start the computer up. I have tried to write a script and can't seem to figure it out. Help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: You can also add the script on startup, search for startup and add the script there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of[why-doesnt-rc-local-run-all-my-commands-and-what-can-i-do-about-it](http://askubuntu.com/questions/239600/why-doesnt-rc-local-run-all-my-commands-and-what-can-i-do-about-it)

Comment: yes i do. I also tried running it from the startup applications and it didn't work either. I imagine I wrote it wrong. I put #!/bin/bash at the top and saved it as a .sh.

Comment: I figured it out. stupid mistake, forgot to change permissions. As you can tell this is new

Comment: @frost58 glad you figured it out! can you please write it out as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

To add the script to the statup I wrote a bash script and found it with the startup applications program. My problem was changing the scripts permissions to executable before running it