# Can I use fractions/decimals in a bash script?

Tags: bash, scripts, calculator

Is there a certain syntax to use while using fractions or decimals in a bash script?

I tried using the following script (in Ubuntu 12.04):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
{
n=9
echo "$n"
for (( i=.5; $i <10; i++ ));
      do
      let "c=$i+1"
      echo $i "+" $c
done
}
```

This works with `i=1`, but it generates a syntax error when I put in `.5`.

Comment: Why exactly do you need this? You can't have half an iteration in a `for` loop so it's a syntax error

Comment: also asked at http://stackoverflow.com/q/19600448/7552

Answer (score 8):

Yeah bash only handles integers but you can route around the issue, either by not using bash (Python is very simple to pick up) or by using `bc` to handle the calculations.

Remember that your condition in your for loop isn't going to work at fractions so you'll need to expand that too.

```
step="0.5"

for (( i=0; $i<$(bc<<<"10/$step"); i++ )); do
      echo $(bc<<<"$step * $i")
done
```

That'll echo `0` through `9.5` in `0.5` increments.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to fake fractions, a bit awkward but it is usable in some cases:

```
#!/bin/bash
{
n=9
echo "$n"

for (( i=5; $i <100; i+=10 ))
do
    let "c=$i+10"
    echo "$(( $i / 10 )).$(( $i % 10 )) + $(( $c / 10 )).$(( $c % 10 ))"
done
}
```

With div/modulo you can also actually do some nifty (read: awkward) calculations.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
{ 
n=9; 
echo "$n"; 
for i in `seq .5 10`;       
do       
c=`bc <<< $i+1`;       
echo $i "+" $c; done; 
}
```

Comment: I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about how this works since OP is (implicitly) asking for an explanation. Also, plain command sequences are rarely considered an answer. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)

Answer (score 1):

### You can use [Zsh](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/).

Most shells, including Bash, don't directly support [floating-point computations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic), and [**as Oli has explained**](https://askubuntu.com/a/366259/22949), the typical workaround is to call [`bc`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/bc.1.html). However, [you have a number of other options](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40786/how-to-do-integer-float-calculations-in-bash-or-other-languages-frameworks).

One of them is to use **the Z Shell**. [`zsh`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/zsh.1.html) is a [Bourne-style shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell#Bourne_shell) ([same "family"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145522/what-does-it-mean-to-be-sh-compatible) as Bash) that does directly support floating point computations. So if you're willing to make it a Zsh script instead of a Bash script, you can do that by changing the first line of your script from `#!/bin/bash` to `#!/bin/zsh`.

Once you do that, it will automatically work! *In this case*, no further modifications to the script are required. (Sometimes, a Bash feature and the corresponding Zsh feature work differently so translating a script from Bash to Zsh requires you to make changes. Though sometimes a Bash script with mistakes in it can actually *become* correct when treated as a Zsh script, due to [different design decisions in Zsh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/171347/11938) about what [expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions) should be performed automatically.)

This is the output:

```
9
0.5000000000 + 1.5000000000
1.5000000000 + 2.5000000000
2.5000000000 + 3.5000000000
3.5000000000 + 4.5000000000
4.5000000000 + 5.5000000000
5.5000000000 + 6.5000000000
6.5000000000 + 7.5000000000
7.5000000000 + 8.5000000000
8.5000000000 + 9.5000000000
9.5000000000 + 10.5000000000
```

**You'll need Zsh installed for it to run.** Zsh does not generally come preinstalled on Ubuntu but it's provided by the `zsh` package. If you don't have `zsh` then you'll see an error like:

```
-bash: ./your-script: /bin/zsh: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Ubuntu's `zsh` package gives you both `/bin/zsh` and `/usr/bin/zsh`. If you want your script to be portable to other systems that have Zsh but in different places, then you might want to use this [hashbang line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/238002/is-bin-sh-read-by-the-interpreter) at the top of your script instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
```

If the user can run Zsh by typing `zsh` and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then putting that at the top of a script will usually work (and run the same `zsh` executable the user would run). That won't work on 100% of systems--technically, [`env`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/env.1.html) does not itself have to be provided in `/usr/bin`--but in practice it's quite rare for it to fail, provided that `zsh` is in the user's [`$PATH`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)#Unix_and_Unix-like).

*For more information on arithmetic evaluation in Zsh, including floating-point arithmetic, see [**11 Arithmetic Evaluation**](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Arithmetic-Evaluation.html#Arithmetic-Evaluation) in The [**Z Shell Manual**](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/index.html#Top).*

### Decreasing Output Precision

A floating-point variable `x` in Zsh may show more precision than you want when you expand it like `$x`:

```
% ((x=.5))
% echo "$x"
0.5000000000
```

One way to expand it without those extra zeros is to use arithmetic expansion instead:

```
% echo "$((x))"
0.5
```

You can also [use the `printf` command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/167059/11938) to display a value with limited precision:

```
% printf '%.2f\n' "$x"
0.50
```

That works in other shells, too, even when the shell doesn't support floating-point arithmetic. (Some shells don't have a `printf` builtin, but you can still use that command because [a standalone-executable version](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/printf.1.html) is installed at `/usr/bin/printf`.) The `printf` command *won't* perform other arithmetic, though, besides rounding.

Even in situations where you don't need numeric formatting, [`printf` is often a better choice than `echo` in shell scripts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo).

In case you're interested, the Zsh manual (as referenced above) explains how precisely floating point-values are actually stored. (Usually it's [IEEE 754 binary64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format).)

### You can use simpler syntax (in Bash, too).

Your script is okay as it is, but you can simplify its syntax for improved readability:

- Your script doesn't need [the grouping provided by `{` and `}`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html#Command-Grouping).
- A `;` is redundant at the end of a line.
- Inside `((` `))`, `$i` can just be written `i`.
- You can use `((` `))` rather than `let`. Without a leading `$`, it evaluates without expanding to the result. Not all shells support this non-expansion form, but Bash and Zsh (and some others) do.
- [It's good to quote when you don't want word-splitting to occur](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells) even when doing so is optional (as in this case). But you can enclose more than one expansion in the same double-quoted span of text.

Leaving out the bit about `n` at the beginning (you may very well need that for your purpose, but I cannot tell what it's for), I suggest:

```
#!/bin/zsh

for ((i = .5; i < 10; i++))
do
    ((c = i + 1))
    echo "$i + $c"
done
```

Or, if you don't want those extra zeros to be printed:

```
#!/bin/zsh

for ((i = .5; i < 10; i++))
do
    echo "$((i)) + $((i + 1))"
done
```

This prints:

```
0.5 + 1.5
1.5 + 2.5
2.5 + 3.5
3.5 + 4.5
4.5 + 5.5
5.5 + 6.5
6.5 + 7.5
7.5 + 8.5
8.5 + 9.5
9.5 + 10.5
```

Finally, to address one point of possible confusion:

- It is okay to assign `i` with `i = .5` because this was evaluated as an arithmetic expression, due to appearing inside `((` `))`, and so spaces around `=` were allowed. The spaces are not required and you need not use them, but you may do so. (I have done so.)
- *Outside* of an arithmetic expression, assigning a shell variable requires there to be no spaces on either side of `=`. That is, normally you must write `var=val`, not `var = val`. Similarly, *outside* of an arithmetic expression, [accessing the value of a shell variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) requires `$` (e.g., `$i`, `${i}`).

Answer (score 1):

I'll point out that while `bash` is limited to integer math, `ksh93` is not. So this (simpler example) works fine:

```
$ for ((i=0.5; i<3; i=$((i+1)))); do print $i ; done
0.5
1.5
2.5
```

We use `i=$((i+1))` rather than `i++` because `++` only works with integers.

So I think this is what the original questioner wants (except of course that it's not being done with `bash`):

```
$ for ((i=0.5; i<10; i=$((i+1)))); do c=$((i+1)) ; print $i + $c ; done
0.5 + 1.5
1.5 + 2.5
2.5 + 3.5
3.5 + 4.5
4.5 + 5.5
5.5 + 6.5
6.5 + 7.5
7.5 + 8.5
8.5 + 9.5
9.5 + 10.5
```

This is all done within the shell itself with no need for external commands. If there is a requirement to use `bash`, then the suggestions that do use external commands are the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

> Bash itself cannot support floating point numbers, but there is a program called bc that can do decimal arithmetic.

You script should be rewrite to use BC (aka Best Calculator) or another [other utility](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/40787/41104). So, how can you do [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/365875/169736)? There is no way that you can use `for` loop since the bash builtin itself doesn't support floating points. Either you use another variable to control inside your loop and use `1` (or `0`) as starting point.

Answer (score 0):

The question is asking to "use fractions/decimals in a bash script?".

Suggestions which "route around the issue, ...by not using bash" are NOT answering the question.

The following bashes a sample decimal:

```
# A crude bash trick for floats
# Bash does NOT do fractions/decimals. 
# Bash does integers (whole numbers).
# A simple loop can solve this though, not a big issue
# example whole number division shown below, results in float answer:

echo -n Enter number to divide:; read n
echo -n to be divided by?:; read div

mult=1      ;# to scale dividend, enabling higher precision quotient

# modify precision in both 'for' loops below,
# 2nd number only
# since they don't accept variables

for i in {1..6}; do mult=$mult"0"; done ;# precision at 6 decimals

result=$(echo -n $((n/div)).)       ;# division, with decimal point
temp=$((n%div*mult/div))        ;# numbers after decimal

echo $result$temp

# ----------------- to remove trailing zeros - OPTIONAL -----------------
# optionally, insignificant zeros may be removed
# many ways of doing this; I'm avoiding any new commands eg. awk, sed, head, tail
# check other topics to remove trailing zeros

#unset temp1

if [ $temp != 0 ]           ;# zero remainders to stay as a float
then

for i in {1..6}; do             # modify precision in both for loops

j=${temp: $((-0-$i)):1}         ;# find trailing zeros

if [ $j != 0 ]              ;# remove trailing zeros
then
    temp1=$temp1"$j"
fi
    done
else 
    temp1=0
fi

temp1=$(echo $temp1 | rev)
echo $result$temp1

# ----------------- OPTION CODE -----------------
```