# Difference between let, expr and $[]

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I want to know what exactly is the difference between

```
a=$[1+1]
a=$((1+1))
let a=1+1
a=$(expr 1 + 1 )
```

All 4 assign the variable a with 2, but what is the difference?

From what I found out so far, is that expr is slower because it is not an actual shell builtin. But not anything more than that.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

All of these deal with arithmetic, but in different ways and the variable is created via different means. Some of these are specific to `bash` shells, while others aren't.

- `$((...))` is called [arithmetic expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_04), which is typical of the `bash` and `ksh` shells. This allows doing simple *integer* arithmetic, no floating point stuff though. The result of the expression replaces the expression, as in `echo $((1+1))` would become `echo 2`
- `((...))` is referred to as [arithmetic evaluation](https://wiki-dev.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/arithmetic_eval) and can be used as part of `if ((...)); then` or `while ((...)) ; do` statements. Arithmetic expansion `$((..))` substitutes the output of the operation and can be used to assign variables as in `i=$((i+1))` but cannot be used in conditional statements.
- `$[...]`  is the old syntax for arithmetic expansion which is deprecated. [See also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2415777/3701431). This was likely kept so that old `bash` scripts don't break. This didn't work in `ksh93`, so my guess is that this syntax is bash-specific. *NOTE*: spaces are very important here; don't confuse `$[1+1]` with stuff like `[ $a -eq $b ]`. The `[` with spaces is known as the `test` command, and you typically see it in decision-making parts. It is very different in behavior and purpose.
- `let` is a `bash` and `ksh` keyword which allows for variable creation with simple arithmetic evaluation. If you try to assign a string there like `let a="hello world"` you'll get a syntax error. Works in `bash` and `ksh93`.
- `$(...)` is command substitution, where you literally take the output of a command and assign to a variable. Your command here is `expr`, which takes positional arguments, like `expr arg1 arg2 arg3`, so spaces are important. It's sort of like a small command-line calculator for integer arithmetic, plus some true/false and regex type of stuff. This is a shell-neutral command.

It's also worth noting that arithmetic expansion and command substitution are specified by [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html), while `let` and `$[...]` aren't.

Comment: `((...))` actually can be used for assignments in `bash`, `ksh` and `zsh`: `n=10; ((n+=10)); echo $n` prints 20 and `((x=1)); echo $x` prints 1.

Comment: @Alexej Thank you. Answer updated, that part removed

Answer (score 12):

- `let` command performs arithmetic **evaluation** and is a shell built-in.

  - Run this command and you get nothing (only evaluates):

    ```
    let 1+2
    ```
- `$(( ))` is used to perform arithmetic **expansion**: [read here](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html)

  - Run this one and you'll get an error (because of expansion):

    ```
    $((1+2))
    ```
- `$[ ]` is the old syntax for arithmetic expansion:

  > The  old format $[expression] is deprecated and will be removed in upcoming of bash.
  >   *Bash Man Page*
- `expr` is a binary command, if you want to do arithmetic expansion within a command subsituation you can use it:

  ```
  echo $(expr 1 + 2) 
  echo `expr 1 + 2`
  ```

Answer (score 5):

Since some of the answers above specifically mention `ksh93` it's worth noting that it can do floating point math, e.g.:

```
$ print $((1.0/3)) 
0.333333333333333333
```

You can control the precision of the output with printf, e.g.:

```
$ printf "%.4f\n" $((1.0/3))
0.3333
```

At least one argument must be specified as a floating-point number as above. If both are specified as integers then only integer math is done, e.g.:

```
$ print $((1/3))  
0
```

This can be helpful when you need floating point math in a shell script since you can avoid calling an external command.

Comment: It occurs to me that you might be interested to post an answer to [Can I use fractions/decimals in a bash script?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/365875/can-i-use-fractions-decimals-in-a-bash-script) In spite of the title, I think the context makes clear that other Bourne-style shells are relevant, which is why I posted [a `zsh` answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/931216/22949). Since `ksh` and `bash` are more similar to each other (in general) than either is to `zsh`, it seems to me that a `kh93`-based answer to that question could be quite useful.

Answer (score 1):

`let` doesn't work in cron. I think that's due to `let` having its own environment. Use `$((...))` since it's POSIX. For example,

```
let x=1+2
echo x=$x
```

in cron, results in "x=", but "x=3" when run from shell.

```
x=$((1+2))
echo x=$x
```

results in "x=3" in all cases.