# What is the function of "$[variable]" command?

Tags: command-line

I learned the following command-

`$[variable]-If set, access the variable`

In this command what type of **variable** it is talking about?

Comment: In what context did you learn this? if you are referring to the bash shell, then `$[expression]` is a (deprecated) form of arithmetic evaluation, so `$[variable]` would be the simplest instance of that, with *expresssion* = *variable*. See for example [Difference between let, expr and $\[\]](https://askubuntu.com/a/939299/178692). It sounds to me like what you *actually* saw was `${variable}`

Comment: I learned it from a cheat sheet it is written there as it is written in the question or nothing else

Comment: Can you show us that cheat sheet you are talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use variables to store and manipulate numbers or strings. **`bash`** is the standard shell in Ubuntu, and it uses variables like the following examples with a variable with the name `var1`:

Set the variable (give it a value)

```
var1="Hello World"
```

Print the variable to the screen

```
echo "$var1"
```

There are several useful tutorials, that you find if you search the internet, for example with the search string **bash variable tutorial**, for example

[ryanstutorials.net/bash-scripting-tutorial/bash-variables.php](https://ryanstutorials.net/bash-scripting-tutorial/bash-variables.php)

---

The manual `man bash` writes the following about **Arithmetic Expansion**,

> Arithmetic expansion allows the evaluation of an arithmetic expression
>   and the substitution of the result.  The  format for arithmetic expansion is:
>
> ```
>           $((expression))
> ```
>
> The old format `$[expression]` is deprecated and will be removed in upcoming versions of bash.

Evaluating an expression and printing to the screen,

```
$ echo $((7*8))  # recommended
56
$ echo $[6*9]    # works now, but deprecated
54
```

Comment: Though this doesn't actually address the question.

Comment: @derHugo, You are right, I answered only the general question about variables. Now I have added details about `$[expression]`

Answer (score 0):

$ means to substitute the value of the following expression. I can be used with variables or commands. To use it with commands, parenthesis are placed around the command.

#### Example 1 - variables:

```
x=hello
echo $x
```

this will print "hello" in the terminal

#### Example 2 - commands

Say I have a file named hello.txt with the contents:

```
Hello
world.
Good
Morning
```

Then I can do:

```
echo $(cat hello.txt)
```

the output would be:

```
Hello world. Good Morning
```

#### Example 3 -- Variable command expansion

This can also be used to allow user input in a script. For example say I have a script that executes a file, I can allow the user to specify where the file is and save it as path. Then do:

```
exec $path/file.sh
```

If path="/home/me", then the command would expand to:

```
exec /home/me/file.sh
```

Answer (score -2):

`$[variable]` is referring to a variable that you set with the following command:

`VARIABLE=<path>`

`<path>` can be anything. It can be a path to another drive, a file server, a document, an application, and even a shortcut.

Comment: What does if set means here? Is it mean if the path exist

Comment: `if set` means if you set the variable.

Comment: @TheComputerGeek010101001 can you give an example on how/when to use this specific notation? what is the difference to using `${variable}` or `$variable`

Comment: I use this command to execute home folder by typing " $[/home/souro]" but it shows error "bash: /home/souro: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "/home/souro")"

Comment: You want:
`home=/home/souro`
Then to reference your home folder, just use `$home`.

Comment: No, the command is not like that your answer is wrong

Comment: @Phillip-ZyanKLee-Stockmann there should be none - but let's say you want to print `Value=123456` and your variable=123, than `echo "Value=$variable456"` would fail and you had to use `echo "Value=${variable}456"`

Comment: @derHugo there is a difference between `${}` and `$[]` - steeldriver posted a comment on the question, which explains the difference.

Comment: yeah, but you didn't ask the difference between those...?

Comment: ah Ok now I get it, never mind than ^^