# Why is using the # symbol as a preface not a comment?

Tags: command-line, python

< - - Linux Noob. I am normally on Raspberry, but the # symbol caused me to move my question here.
Attempting to run a script, and failing, I found answers in Raspberry to use the following (preceded by the symbol #):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

[Link here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/15949/my-python-executable-file-wont-open-the-terminal-and-execute)  describes my confusion.  I thought # indicated a comment (in Linux and in Raspberry Python).  I don't understand the # symbol at the beginning of the command prompt.         #!/usr/bin/env python.

Question : Is the # symbol to be typed in?

I suspect the # symbol shows only because that otherwise the command would be executed.

Comment: @Jobin . thank you. I searched but searching for "!" or "#" yielded zero. Good link. Hopefully my question can yield a link for others

Comment: Related: [Is #!/bin/sh read by the interpreter?](http://askubuntu.com/q/238002/22949)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the `#` sign must be used.  This is a special-case comment called a shebang line that causes the program specified (`/usr/bin/env python` in your case) to be run with the path to your program as an argument  [WikiPedia's page on Shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) is very good.

Comment: I saw a reference in my link to "Shebang", but thought that was a slang word.  Live and learn.  Nice to know.