# How can I extract the last X chars from a string variable?

Tags: bash

I'm reading the last line of a file into a variable. Then I want to get the last X characters of the string variable:

```
#!/bin/bash
someline="this is the last line content"
echo ${someline}
somepart=${someline: -5}
echo ${somepart}
```

Run with: `sh lastchars.sh`

Result:

```
this is the last line content
line 4: Bad substitution
```

What might be wrong here?

Comment: What gives the actual error? The `echo`? If so, please show us the contents of the `$line` variable. Do you also get the error if you use quotes (`echo "${lastchars}"`)?

Comment: Your code works exactly like it's supposed to for me, please add input and full output to your question.

Comment: the `${line}` content prints just fine. anyways the substitution error is shown. @terdon the `echo ${lastchars}` is not reached at all, because getting the last 5 characters from the variable already produces the error.

Comment: I can't reproduce what you describe. Are you *sure* you're using bash? Are you running this in a script or from the command line? If a script, how are you running that script?

Comment: I added the complete example above. I cannot help, still getting the error of this...

Comment: That's because you're using the wrong shell. You're not running bash at all but instead are using `sh` which is a different shell: `dash`. See my answer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It sounds like you're not using `bash` at all. I can only reproduce the error you show if I use `dash` instead of `bash`:

1. `bash`:

   ```
   $ line="someline content"
   $ echo ${line}
   someline content
   $ lastchars=${line: -5}
   $ echo ${lastchars}
   ntent
   ```
2. `dash`:

   ```
   $ line="someline content"
   echo ${line}
   lastchars=${line: -5}
   echo ${lastchars}
   $ someline content
   $ dash: 3: Bad substitution
   ```

Your [shebang line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) is pointing to `bash`, but you are running the script with `sh`, so the shebang is ignored. `/bin/sh` on Ubuntu systems is actually `dash`, a minimal shell that doesn't support the syntax you are trying to use.

When using a shebang line, there's no reason to explicitly call a shell for the script, just make it executable (`chmod a+x /path/to/script.sh`) and run it without specifying an interpreter:

```
/path/to/script.sh
```

Alternatively, just use the right one:

```
bash /path/to/script.sh
```

Comment: I have the  `#!/bin/bash` and still getting the error. Interestingly running the script with `bash lastchars.sh` works! Do you know why?

Comment: @membersound yes, because you are running it as `sh lastchars.sh`. The `#!/bin/bash` is ignored if you run it with a specific shell.  So either run it directly (`lastchars.sh`) or run it with bash (`bash lastchars.sh`).

Comment: Ok so that's probably the solution.

Comment: @membersound For details about why the `#!/bin/bash` line is ignored when you run `sh lastchars.sh`, see [Is #!/bin/sh read by the interpreter?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/238002/is-bin-sh-read-by-the-interpreter) (which applies to any "hashbang" line, including `#!/bin/bash`, and not just to `#!/bin/sh`).

Answer (score 1):

Obviously using the build-in functions of a certain shell are nice, but you can also accomplish the task using standard UNIX commands, so it will work in any shell:

```
String="This is some text"
StrLen=`echo ${String} | wc -c`
From=`expr $StrLen - 5`
echo $String | cut -c${From}-${StrLen}
```