# ./ vs . for running programs under terminal

Tags: command-line, executable

I'd need some clarification regarding the way we run executables under the terminal. This might be a lame question but what is the difference between running an executable with `./an_executable` and `. an_executable` (let's suppose that we are in the dir where an_executable is located)

I already know that the former makes the shell look for an_executable in the current directory (`.`), but why isn't a `/` needed after `.` when using the latter version?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See also http://askubuntu.com/q/182012/26972

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `. executable` syntax doesn't work with just any executable (or does it?). Instead, it's an alias for the bash `source` built-in. So the difference is mostly relevant to bash scripts, and the truth is that they're completely different things :)

`./executable` asks to run the executable "normally". `./` is a relative reference to the current path. This avoids having the shell (bash) try to locate the executable in a directory in its `$PATH` (which it would do if you didn't specify a path at all with the command). The reason why you can't just do `executable` is one of security; imagine you uncompress an archive you downloaded and it contains a malicious version of `ls`. If it ran directly from your current directory, you'd run that version without realizing.

On the other hand, `. executable` is saying "source a file named `executable`". Since you're directly naming the file and it really doesn't have to be an executable, the security restriction for the $PATH doesn't apply. Sourcing will only "run" (or seem to run) shell scripts. What it does is:

```
   source filename [arguments]
          Read and execute commands from filename  in  the  current  shell
          environment  and return the exit status of the last command exe‐
          cuted from filename.
```

So... What's really the difference between executing and sourcing? Assuming the same shell script, executing it (`./script`) will spawn a new shell, run the script inside that shell, and when the script exits, close that shell and return to the parent shell. In effect, it will start a new `bash` process to execute the script).

(`. script`) will cause the *current* shell to read the commands from the file as if they were being typed in the command line. There's no new shell spawned.

A very easy way to see how this behaves is to write a script that only contains `exit`. If you `./script` it, nothing will seem to happen, this is because a new shell process is started, the `exit` command exits that *new* shell and your current shell is unaffected.

If you `. script`, you current terminal will close, because the `exit` command runs in the current shell. So it's equivalent to typing `exit` on the command prompt.

Comment: Indeed, I was dealing with shell script when I noticed this behaviour. Thank you very much, thats the answer I needed. :)

Comment: another question raised (if you don't mind):

if my script contains just some simple messages with echo, and I am running it with ./script, then why am I able to see the messages in the parent shell if the subshell closes as soon as the execution ends?

Comment: Because while the subshell is a separate *process*, it uses the same *terminal* as the invoking shell. It's similar to how you're still able to see `ls` output: you type the command, it runs, shows the output and then it ends, but the output remains in the terminal.

Comment: Don't confuse shell with terminal; they're different things. Open a terminal, and the command prompt is given by a `bash` shell running inside it. If you type `bash`, you'll be running *another* shell; to the first shell, it's just a program to be run. If you type `exit`, you'll close the *last* shell you started but still be in the first shell (the one from when you started the terminal). Again, this all happens within the same terminal.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that `. executable` _only_ works for shell scripts, but does nothing (or perhaps bad things) if `executable` is a compiled program or a script in a different language.

Comment: @DavidZ I did mention it :) "Sourcing will only "run" (or seem to run) shell scripts."

Comment: Ah, yes, I missed that. It's kind of buried in the middle there.

Comment: The easiest way to see the difference is to set an environment variable in your script. It's impossible to affect the environment of a parent process, so a variable set in a script run with `./` won't be visible in the shell where you run it, while one set in one run with `.` will. E.g. `echo export foo=bar >script;chmod +x script;./script; echo $foo` vs. `echo export foo=bar >script;. script; echo $foo`--the former will print a blank line, while the latter will print `bar`.

Comment: Thanks!  An upvote *and* an edit (though minor...)  **;-)**