# How to run source on terminal start up?

Tags: alias

I have alias ready on `.bash_aliases`.
Problem I'm having right now is that I need to run `source ~/.<filename>` first before I can execute the alias command.

My question would be how do I run the `source ~/.<filename>` when user opens terminal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might put `source ~/.bash_aliases` in your `~/.bashrc` file, or actually define aliases there.

[Some background.](http://hacktux.com/bash/bashrc/bash_profile)

Comment: Normally, ~/.bash_alieases file is already sourced in ~/.bashrc file, so you don't need to do it again. See [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/334879/147044).

Comment: @RaduRădeanu well I know, but I suppose if the alias doesn't work from `.bash_aliases` then it might be that the user messed up with sourcing the file. It was my assumption too that if the line is present they may also notice that aliases file is already sourced and ask why it doesn't work, but messed-up syntax or other errors in `.bashrc` is IMO not relevant to this specific question, at least in its present form.

Answer (score 0):

Just mention that .bash_alieases script into .profile in your home directory. 
something like that

cat >> ~/.profile

/bin/sh ~/.bash_alieases

cltd+d

Next time whenever you open a terminal it will execute that .bash_alieases file automatically.

Comment: It is not a good idea to source `~/.bash_alieases` file in `~/.profile` file. This file is not read by bash(1), if `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bash_login` exists. Normally, `~/.bash_alieases` file is already sourced in `~/.bashrc` file.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to source `~/.bash_alieases` file in `~/.bashrc` file. If you look with attention in `~/.bashrc` file you will find somewhere after line 100 the following lines:

```bsh
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

This mean: if the file `~/.bash_aliases` exists and is a regular file, then execute the file. `source ~/.bash_aliases` and `. ~/.bash_aliases` are synonymous in bash (see [What is the difference between "source" and "." in bash?](https://askubuntu.com/q/25488/147044)).

Only if by some mistake you don't have the above lines you should add them again in your `~/.bashrc` file.

Finally, if you are interested to run any other file on terminal start up, a good way is to source that file inside `~/.bashrc` file as follow:

```
source ~/<filename>
```

or, simple:

```
. ~/<filename>
```