# unable to locate packages fg in ubuntu 18.04.3

Tags: apt, software-installation

```
sudo apt install fg
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package fg
```

Comment: Possibly related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/613470/where-are-commands-fg-bg-and-jobs-installed/613477

Comment: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=fg  -- what package `fg` ?

Comment: Results of `type fg`: `fg is a shell builtin`

Answer (score 0):

*fg* is not a package by itself, nor can you install it independently. It is part of the [bash shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) which is installed when Ubuntu is installed.