# 'source' builtin in bash not recognized in cron environment

Tags: 14.04, bash, cron, alias

A user crontab entry that reads:

```
0 */4 * * * $HOME/postscript/fprogcache-sync
```

works fine. Wanting to add a few environment variables to the cron-job context, I then tried

```
0 */4 * * * source $HOME/.profile; $HOME/postscript/fprogcache-sync
```

That did not work until I changed `source` for `.`. The error message (sent by postfix mail to root) was `/bin/sh: 1: source: not found`, followed by confirmation that the script went on to execute happily.

I remember having read somewhere that `source` is defined as an alias of the builtin `.` in the bash shell. If so, it would explain why `source` is not recognized in the cron context.

Is it the case? If so, where is the system wide alias  for `.` defined?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is it the case? If so, where is the system wide alias  for `.` defined?

It is the case, but there's no such thing as a system-wide alias.

`.` and `source` are the same builtin in Bash, but that's defined directly at the source code's level (https://askubuntu.com/a/25491/380067).

The reason behind having two names for the same builtin most likely resides in the fact that [Bash aims to be POSIX-compliant to some extent](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-POSIX-Mode.html); so `source` for the sake of providing a mnemonic name and `.` for the sake of complying with POSIX's standards.

The real reason why `source` doesn't work in `cron` is that by default `cron` jobs in the crontab are excuted in `sh`, which is a symlink to `/bin/dash` (a shell that aims to be POSIX-compliant as well) which simply doesn't implement `source`. However it does implement `.`.

From `man dash`:

```
. file
       The commands in the specified file are read and executed by the
       shell.
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should run your script on bash, try this :

`0 */4 * * * /bin/bash -c "$HOME/postscript/fprogcache-sync"`

and if you want to add log in your command and debug scripts add log like this :

`0 */4 * * * /bin/bash -c "$HOME/postscript/fprogcache-sync" > /var/log/automatic_backup.log 2>&1`