# What does . in . .bash_profile mean?

Tags: command-line, bash

The command `. .bash_profile` is used to reload(?) bash_profile. What is the general purpose of the first `.`? How it can be used and is there a resource to read about these type symbols of Terminal?

Comment: The `help` command helps, see: [How can I get help on terminal commands?](https://askubuntu.com/q/991946/507051)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The command `.` is a shell built-in. It executes the shell script you give as argument, but within your current shell environment. This is also called "sourcing" a script. In Bash, `source` is therefore a synonym of `.` (but e.g. not in `sh` or in the POSIX standard). Also see [What is the difference between "source" and "."?](https://askubuntu.com/q/25488/367990)

Sourcing a script (like `. ~/.bashrc`) is different to regularly running a script (like `~/.bashrc`) in that if you run it normally, it will run inside a sub-shell instead of the current shell environment.

A sub-shell has its own working directory, shell options and local variables, so that changing them within the script (e.g. by using `cd` or setting/changing variables) does not affect the parent shell. If you run a script, it will also only get read access to those local variables of the parent shell which it `export`ed, not the regular ones.

If you want to allow the script to modify your current environment (e.g. to change shell options, set environment variables, create aliases and functions which you then can use, etc), which is the case for `.bashrc`, you have to source it. If you just ran it, all its changes would be lost as soon as it exits and returns to your shell environment.

More info can be obtained by running `help .` or `help source`, and [`man bash` (section about shell built-ins)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/bash.1.html#contenttoc30).

Comment: I thought `.` and `source` would have been duplicate by now but I couldn't find one. So +1 :)